# How can I select distinct column combinations from a DataTable object with another column as a condition?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm using C# 2010.

I have a DataTable object I'm working with which has the following structure (and is filled with sample data):

```
"name"    "ID"    "hiredate"    "termdate"
Bobby     1        5/1/2011       7/1/2011
Peggy     2        5/1/2011
Jenny     3        5/2/2011
Jenny     3        5/2/2013
Jenny     3        5/2/2011       6/1/2011
Peggy     2        5/1/2011
```

I want to filter this DataTable to keep only distinct ("ID","hiredate") combinations. Furthermore, as you can see, not everyone has a "termdate" value. When deciding which distinct ("ID","hiredate") combination to keep, I want to keep the one that also has a "termdate". If there's no "termdate" in any of them it doesn't matter which one is discarded.

So the resulting table after doing this would be:

```
"name"    "ID"    "hiredate"    "termdate"
Bobby     1        5/1/2011       7/1/2011
Peggy     2        5/1/2011
Jenny     3        5/2/2013
Jenny     3        5/2/2011       6/1/2011
```

Jenny has two entries because she appeared with two different "hiredate" values, and one of them was also duplicated - the entry without the "termdate" was removed.

Any suggestions for how to do this in C#? Again, I'm using a DataTable object. I still need to keep the "name" and "termdate" fields - if I didn't, then I was able to get a distinct ("ID","hiredate") list, but they really need to be retained.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you filling the data table in the 1st place? That might be the best place to filter this out if it is coming from a database.

Comment: It's being read in from a CSV file and possibly user input, so filtering with a SQL command is not the preferred option.

Comment: Ah, I see, shame that would have made it much easier.. Will post what I would do with the datatable below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do something like this, dt is your original datatable -

This should cover all eventualities due to the ordering of the data view, the date list which is maintained allows the addition of multiple hire dates for a user.

```
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.Sort = "ID ASC, HireDate DESC, TermDate DESC";

            string lastID = "0";
            List<DateTime> addedHireDatesForUser = new List<DateTime>();

            foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
            {
                if (drv["ID"].ToString() != lastID)
                {
                    addedHireDatesForUser = new List<DateTime>();
                    addedHireDatesForUser.Add(DateTime.Parse(drv["HireDate"].ToString()));

                    // NEXT ID, ADD ROW TO NEW DATATABLE
                }
                else if (!addedHireDatesForUser.Contains(DateTime.Parse(drv["HireDate"].ToString())))
                {
                    addedHireDatesForUser.Add(DateTime.Parse(drv["HireDate"].ToString());

                    // NEXT DATE, ADD ROW TO NEW DATATABLE
                }

                lastID = drv["ID"].ToString();
            }
```

Comment: just had to tweak a few things and it worked perfectly. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo-code and untested but this might get you started.

```
       //Get rows with distinct name, ID hiredate
        DataView dview = new DataView(table);
        DataTable distinctValues = dview.ToTable(true, "name", "ID", "hiredate");

        //Get rows with termdate not null
        DataView tview = new DataView(table, "Isnull(termdate,'') <> ''", "ID", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        DataTable termValues = tview.ToTable(true, "name", "ID", "hiredate", "termdate");

        DataTable result = new DataTable("Table");
        foreach (DataRow r in distinctValues.Rows)
        {
            DataRow[] compare = termValues.Select(string.Format("name='{0}' AND ID='{1}' AND hiredate='{2}'", r["name"], r["ID"], r["hiredate"]));
            //If a value exists with a termdate use it
            if (compare != null && compare.Length > 0)
            {
                DataRow row = result.NewRow();
                row["name"] = compare[0]["name"];
                row["ID"] = compare[0]["ID"];
                row["hiredate"] = compare[0]["hiredate"];
                row["termdate"] = compare[0]["termdate"];
                result.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            // Otherwise use the distinct value
            else
            {
                DataRow row = result.NewRow();
                row["name"] = r["name"];
                row["ID"] = r["ID"];
                row["hiredate"] = r["hiredate"];
                result.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i went with the other one because it was more fleshed out and i'm in a bit of a time crunch, but i will definitely revisit this when i come back to do further refinement on my code.

Answer (score 0):

To get a distinct list of values from a datatable...

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
DataTable dtResults = dv.ToTable(true, "name", "ID", "hiredate");
```

then place termdates...

```
dtResults.Columns.Add("termdate", typeof(DateTime));
foreach (DataRow dr in from x in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() where !x.IsNull("termdate") select x) {
    DataRow drResult = dtResults.Select(string.Format("name=\'{0}\' and ID=\'{1}\' and hiredate=\'{2}\'", dr["name"], dr["ID"], dr["hiredate"])).Single();
    drResult["termdate"] = dr["termdate"];
}
```

Comment: I do believe this solution would work fine. However, I prefer the other ones since I may have additional columns in the future, so listing them all out may become unwieldy.